# Why my processes are executed in a sequential order?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am playing with Python's multiprocessing module. I started with this program:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
```

To my surprise, the results are always this:

```
Worker: 0
Worker: 1
Worker: 2
Worker: 3
Worker: 4
```

I would expect that the workers are output in  a different order from time to time, but that never happened no matter how many times I run the program. Where did I misunderstand?

Comment: The processes are started sequentially, not simultaneously.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Your comment could be misleading. Please refer to Reut's answer below.

Comment: Adding a random sleep doesn't invalidate my comment.

Comment: Ignacio is correct. The process are started sequentially, that doesn't mean they are ended sequentially. If there was a way to start them together with no bias you'd get random order as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, its just very fast. Try this to add some jittering:

```
import multiprocessing
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    sleep(randint(0, 5))
    print 'Worker:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
```